# Why using Gunicorn with GEvent could increate the query time to Redis/Database?

Tags: python, django, redis, gunicorn, gevent

In actual production load (web app) with an Redis server (v4.x) when using gunicorn with worker_class `gevent` the query time increases by 3. Database access also got worse (but not so much, only 50%). I'm trying to figure out why this would happen. Any ideas? The app is very IO Bound, with lots of database queries and redis accesses for every single request, which should be the perfect scenario for `gevent`.

*Moving from SYNC to GEVENT (~11 A.M)*

[image: Query time increase after moving from SYNC to GEVENT]

Would the monkey patching to the socket decrease performance somehow? I tried to fine tuning `worker_connections` without success, even the extremely low level of just 2 (almost sync again), give me the same bad results. Am I missing some gotcha for how `gevent` and it's pseudothreads work?

Disclaimer: I'm using NewRelic to monitor the performance and redis-py/django/mysql. I tried some tweaks like using the BlockingConnectionPool for Redis, but my Database access performance also decreased so Redis is not the only problem. The worker size is 5 (CPUs * 2 + 1). I also had tons of GreenletExit/ConnectionError[redis] at random times, which was minimized by moving `worker_connections` from 2k (default) to `10`.

Comment: Some code would greatly help us.

Comment: I don't have an specifc portion of code to share. Imagine a Django app, with some cache access (probably 5 or more calls), some more database accesses (30+ calls), middlewares as usual. The "usual web stuff".

Comment: More in how you are instantiating the redis connectionpool.  I use redis with gevent and my performance is excellent.  But I had to realize that redis creates a connectionpool.

Answer (score 0):

Example of a redis connection after monkeypatching.

```
_rconn = None
def redisconn():
    global _rconn
    if _rconn is None:
        try:
            _rconn = redis.StrictRedis(host=redisconfig['host'], port=redisconfig['port'], db=redisconfig['db'])
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            _rconn = None
    return _rconn

class RedisCache(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #in case of a lost connection lets sit and wait till it's online
        global _rconn
        if not _rconn:
            while not _rconn:
                try:
                    redisconn()
                except:
                    print('Attempting Connection To Redis...')
                    gsleep(1)
        self.r = _rconn
        self.rpool = self.r.connection_pool

    def get(self, key):
        return self.r.get(key)

    def set(self, key, meta, expire=86400, nx=True):
        return self.r.set(key, json.loads(meta), ex=expire, nx=nx)

    def connections(self):
        return self.rpool._created_connections

    def inuse(self):
        return self.rpool._in_use_connections
```